# Простейшая админ панель для работы с БД

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, администрирование, админка

Появилась необходимость создать админ панель для администрирования базы пользователей 2мя-3мя людьми. Так как я новичок в этом деле, прошу совета, возможно посоветуете подходящий ресурс, в гугле в основом примеры работы с wordpress и с различными лэндингами через админ панель, но в моем случае все это излишне. Нужна лишь простейшая админка для работы с БД.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под администрирование БД? Чем Вам тот же phpmyadmin не угодил?

Comment: А `virtualmin` какой-нить не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользовался yii2 framework, у него так же присутствует необходимый для вас CRUD генератор, а также множество дополнительных - готовых виджетов, которые позволят вам касмомизировать ваше приложение под ваши потребности.
Плюсом будет довольно большое и отзывчивое комьюнити.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать любой CRUD генератор. Например для Laravel их большое количество, в том числе с бесплатной лицензией. Один из них https://backpackforlaravel.com/

Или найти CMS на базе фреймворка (october cms, laravel nova, sulu cms, youpe)